# Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle12c

I am getting this error in oracle 12c.

[image: Auto generated local connections are working but when i am trying to create a new connection i am getting this error]

[image: "lsnrctl status" from cmd shows without any error]

Comment: if i use SID instead service name while creating connection properties it gives me, Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

But in sqlplus everything works fine.

Comment: Are you running both the SQL Developer and SQL*Plus from the same machine?

Comment: Yes i am running both in same machine.